# Problems in compile scala project using SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying to run a Scala project using SBT.
On compiling the project I am getting the below error -

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Symbol 'type scalaxb.XMLStandardTypes' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'trait connectors.concept.XMLProtocol'.
Make sure that type XMLStandardTypes is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'XMLProtocol.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scalaxb.]
at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
        at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1(PlayReload.scala:40)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:35)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:28)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$compile$3(PlayReload.scala:63)
        at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:63)
```

my project is using **scalaVersion = "2.13.3"** and **SBT version is = "1.3.13"**.

Any pointers on how to compile this.

Below are my build.sbt and plugins.sbt files -

**build.sbt** file -

```
name := "test-manager"

organization := "zest"
resolvers in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
 Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
 Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
 "Zest releases" at "https://test/test-releases",
 "Zest snapshots" at "https://test/test-snapshots"
)

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"

lazy val compactEvolutions        = TaskKey[Unit]("compactEvolutions")

lazy val yarnBuild                = taskKey[Unit]("Build frontend dependencies using yarn")

lazy val yarnWatch                = taskKey[Unit]("Watch frontend dependencies using yarn")

lazy val supportedLanguages = Seq("en")

DefaultOptions.addCredentials

lazy val packageSettings = Seq(
 maintainer in Linux := "test@test",
 packageSummary in Linux := "Custom startscript parameters",
 packageName in Linux := name.value,
 packageDescription := "Custom startscript parameters",
 daemonUser in Linux := "test_api",
 daemonGroup in Linux := "test_api",
 // rpm specific
 rpmRelease := "1",
 rpmVendor := "test",
 rpmUrl := Some("http://test"),
 rpmLicense := Some("Private"),
 rpmGroup := Some("permission"),
 //File mappings setting. Exclude all resource files
 mappings in (Compile, packageBin) := {
   val resourceFilenames = (resources in Compile).value.map(_.getName)
   (mappings in (Compile, packageBin)).value.filterNot {
     case (_, name) =>
       resourceFilenames.contains(name)
   }
 },
 scriptClasspath := "/test/conf" +: scriptClasspath.value
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
 .enablePlugins(PlayScala, JavaAppPackaging, SystemdPlugin, RpmDeployPlugin)
 .settings(packageSettings: _*)
 .settings(
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     guice,
     ws,
     filters,
     "com.typesafe.play"          %% "play-json"            % "2.8.1",
     "org.mockito"                % "mockito-all"           % "1.10.19" % Test,
     "org.scalatestplus.play"     %% "scalatestplus-play"   % "5.1.0"   % Test,
     "com.norbitltd"              %% "spoiwo"               % "1.8.0",
     "com.univocity"              % "univocity-parsers"     % "2.9.0",
     "org.tpolecat"               %%  "doobie-core"         % "0.9.0",
     "org.tpolecat"               %%  "doobie-hikari"       % "0.9.0",
     "org.tpolecat"               %%  "doobie-postgres"     % "0.9.0",
     "org.tpolecat"               %%  "doobie-scalatest"    % "0.9.0"   % Test,
     "com.github.tomakehurst"     %   "wiremock-standalone" % "2.27.1"  % Test,
     "org.flywaydb"               %   "flyway-core"         % "6.5.5",
     "ch.qos.logback"             %   "logback-classic"     % "1.2.3",
     "org.dispatchhttp"           %% "dispatch-core"        % "1.1.3",
     "org.scala-lang.modules"     %% "scala-xml"            % "1.3.0",
     "org.scala-lang.modules"     %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.1.2",
     "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.7",
     "org.typelevel" %% "cats-laws" % "2.1.1",
     "de.svenkubiak" % "jBCrypt" % "0.4.1",
     "io.github.jyllands-posten" %% "play-prometheus-filters" % "0.6.0"
   ),
   javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf",
   javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8"),
   scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8",
   maxErrors := 50,
   routesImport += "common.Bindables._",
   compactEvolutions := {
     DbCompactor.compactEvolutions()
   },
   yarnBuild := {
     scala.sys.process.Process("yarn" :: "build" :: Nil) ! new process.ProcessLogger {
       override def out(s: => String): Unit =
         println(s)
       override def err(s: => String): Unit =
         println(s)
       override def buffer[T] (f: => T): T = f
     }
   },
   yarnWatch := {
     scala.sys.process.Process("yarn" :: "watch" :: Nil) run new process.ProcessLogger {
       override def out(s: => String): Unit =
         println(s)
       override def err(s: => String): Unit =
         println(s)
       override def buffer[T] (f: => T): T = f
     }
   }
 )


addCommandAlias("generate-bundles", "test:runMain common.sheets.BundleGenerator")
addCommandAlias("run-local", "run -Dconfig.resource=local.conf")
addCommandAlias("run-dev", "; yarnWatch; run-local")
```

and **plugins.sbt** file -

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.7"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.2")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "2.4.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.6.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.4")

addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.paradox" % "sbt-paradox" % "0.8.0")

addSbtPlugin("io.github.jonas" % "sbt-paradox-material-theme" % "0.6.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.13")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")
```

I have tried to add scalaxb dependency in both the build.sbt and plugins.sbt file.
But still getting the same error.

Also I have compiled the project with scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"
and there is only one scalaxb jar is bieng used.

Comment: Do you have `addSbtPlugin("org.scalaxb" % "sbt-scalaxb" % "X.X.X")
 
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public")` at your `plugins.sbt` like it is saying here https://scalaxb.org/sbt-scalaxb ?

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I have tried this but still getting the same error.
Also, I have tried to add the scalaxb dependency in the build.sbt file as well but still the same error.

Comment: I can't compile your settings. Can you please create [mre]?